# Как изменить пароль пользователя root в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как изменить пароль пользователя root в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

в терминале - `sudo passwd root`

Answer (score 2):

Открываем при запуске recovery mode

Прежде чем писать команду на смену пароля необходимо сделать

```
mount -no remount,rw /
```

а после уже

```
passwd имя_юзера
```

Answer (score 2):

**Изменение пароля without terminal**

Щёлкните самый правый значок на панели меню и выберите Параметры системы.

Откройте Учётные записи.

Щёлкните табличку рядом с надписью Пароль.

Эта табличка выглядит как ряд точек или квадратиков, если пароль уже есть.

Введите действующий пароль, а затем новый пароль. Введите новый пароль снова в поле Подтвердить пароль.

Щёлкните Изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь в настройки, там будет панелька управления, будет вкладка поменять пароль, там и меняешь.

Comment: пользователя могло интересовать и то как его изменить в консоли. Я бы на Вашем месте написал ответ чуть поподробнее.

Answer (score -1):

Вводим команду в терминал: passwd

Далее подтверждаем старый пароль и добаляем новый

КОД ИЗ ТЕРМИНАЛА:

dron@stef-ThinkPad-Edge-E540:~$ passwd

Changing password for dron.

Current password:

New password:

Retype new password:

passwd: password updated successfully

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: приведённая вами информация — о смене пароля текущего пользователя. вопрос же совершенно о другом.