# Как сбросить свой пароль в Lubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu, взлом, live-usb, lubuntu, chroot

В общем проблема такая, забыл свой пароль, или его кто то поменял.

В общем через recovery mode  не получается система дает сбой.

Как быть?

Comment: Если вкратце: Загружаетесь с любого загрузочного диска linux c правами root, маунтите системный диск,  делаете chroot, затем passwd <user>

Comment: «тысячи их». [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/348348/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432479/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449919/178576), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/16/178576)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Загрузитесь с  Ubuntu Live CD.

Жмёте **Ctrl-Alt-F1**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

sudo passwd <user>
```

**user**  заменяете на свой логин в системе.

Так же может отличаться параметр **sda1**, замените на свой при необходимости.

[Один из источников:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)